Add local jar in pom
Need to add a local jar in pom which does not have group_id and version.
I used below
mvn install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=
but did not work.
getting below error:
error: package com.cingular.csi.csi.namespaces.types.xpublic.cingularDataModel does not exist.

Does this answer your question? How to add local jar files to a Maven project?
